# How can I get the height of a specific row in my UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my `UITableView` i've set different heights for different rows using the delegate method: `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Now given a `NSIndexPath`, I would like to get the height I've previously assigned for a specific row.

Comment: If you have to pick data out of the table view then something has gone wrong. How do you calculate the height in `heightForRow...`? This should either be calculated using data stored in the controller and so can be recalculated. Or if it isn't you should store the heights along side the data.

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm not using a UITableViewController, I guess storing the heights is the only solution than...

Comment: You may not be but you are implementing the `UITableViewControllerDelegate` and `UITableViewControllerDataSource` in a "controller". These should know all the information they need to get the height of a specific row. Without showing any code it's hard to help any more.

Comment: @Fogmeister They help arrived, thanks anyway

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use this

```
CGRect frame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"row height : %f", frame.size.height);
```

Using `frame.size.height` you can get height of particular row

**Swift 3**

```
let frame = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
print(frame.size.height)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Simplly Use

> tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath

method

```
int row = 1;

int section = 0;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

float height = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Hope this wil help for you :)

Comment: Do you suggest to call `heightForRowAtIndexPath:...` which you declare by yourself in most cases?

Answer (score 3):

```
-(CGFloat)getHeightAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   if(indexPath.row == 0)
       return 20.0;
   else if(indexPath.row == 4)
       return 40.0;

  return 50.0; //Default

}
```

Call the above function in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` as

```
return [self getHeightAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And you can use the same function on say button click action of a button inside a specific cell, with having `button.tag=indexPath.row`

```
-(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender{
   UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

   NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag inSection:0];

   CGFloat height=[self getHeightAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using below code you can get the cell height from `tableview`

```
 let height = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
```