# Issue While Finding Height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I am calculating height of Cell programatically in `heightForRowAtIndexPath-`

My complete method is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];

    if([cell isKindOfClass:[Custom class]])
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else
    {
         return 20;
    }
}
```

My app takes `3-5` sec to Show the ViewController. Although `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called and I can show the logs in Console.

But My ViewController not loaded.

When just return the height using this code app works fine:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 100;
}
```

I don't know that is the issue with this line:

```
id cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
```

What I am missing in this issue?

Comment: see this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206448/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-a-specific-row-in-my-uitableview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968316/get-uitableviewcells-height-after-setting-height-for-each-uitableviewcell

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I need to find the type of cell as I have two type of cell. that's the main issue. Whenever i use the code to find the type of cell my app start making delays

Comment: Why don't you use a property isTableViewWithCustomCells or isTableViewWithOtherCustomCells? It should be faster. and I think that `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` may be called before cellForRowAtIndexPath and the dequeue stuff.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254723/how-to-obtain-the-uitableviewcell-within-heightforrowatindexpath

Comment: some times `heightForRowAtIndexPath` call before cellForRowAtIndexPath then what?

Comment: please post code for cell for row at indexpath

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your approach. Why haven't I thought this way .

Comment: Please use UITableviewCell instead of id

Comment: What is name of the Two Type of Custom Cell?

Comment: well I can't see where you are getting height of cell heightForRowAtIndexPath will setup height for row in tableview.

Comment: and why you are setting fixed height for cells, if you want to change height give it dynamic height instead. Calculate height and assign to heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: see answer over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785870/set-dynamic-width-and-height-of-collection-view-cell/38789275#38789275

Answer (score 0):

You have some logic in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method that determines what type of cell that row should be. Add that logic into the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method to determine the what the height of each row should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your this line is wrong

```
id cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
```

it will force your cell to reuse.

Use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCellClass class]])
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else
    {
         return 20;
    }
}
```