# Expandable view and text

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to create an iOS app and I want something like the pics below which when I tap the down arrow, the text and view expand.

I have no idea how it would be possible or even what should I call it.

[image]

Expanded one:

[image]

Edit:
 StoryBoard:
[image]

There is a view for Video player top and a ScrollView down which contains an image and a tableview. what i want is that put the above feature(2 pics above) instead of that image. and scroll all image and tableview up to be behind of video player view

Comment: Which control you have use to show text? like UITextView, UITextFiled, UILabel

Comment: i don't know which one should i use @Er.ShreyanshShah

Comment: up to what level you want to expand the Text container? for example you want to expand up container can be seen full or something else.

Comment: what I've assumed that you have the dotted button to expand and compress the text-container?

Comment: @SaadChaudhry i want to be make text fully seen. for example: if it's three line, expand to that and if it's four extend to appropriate height

Comment: @SaadChaudhry no, the dotted button is for something else. down arrow does this

Comment: @HosAp you want to change the height as user type text or what?

Comment: @SaadChaudhry the data comes from server . i want to show just 2 lines and if the user wants tap on down arrow and the text should be shown completely

Comment: that's something I was saying anyways, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785870/set-dynamic-width-and-height-of-collection-view-cell/38789275#38789275 see this answer and calculate height of your text, assign it to your text container when user taps on down arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Autolaout you extend the height of your textview based on  content size and your view

Comment: how can i use auto layout? i'm quite new to iOS. can you say an example?

Comment: try to online search for auto layout because without it you can't understand auto layout how works.

Answer (score 1):

You need self sizing cell  with tableview automatic dimension you can find tutorial for that

in label set number of lines 2 and line break mode to truncate tail initially ,

on tap of button action you need to set number of line 0 and line break mode world wrap , and use `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate` tableview

Answer (score 0):

You have to add action (selector) to the button and in it you have to modify the frame and properties of containting view. Please post some code/storyboard for detailed answer.